# Issues executing with ActivePerl 5.20

Tags: perl

I have a program which uses a module, located at the same folder that the executable but when I execute it it only closes.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use genLetras;




for my $k (1 .. 30 ) {
        for my $j (1 .. 30 ) {
        genLetras::generarLetra();
        $matriz[$k][$j] = genLetras::generarLetra();
   }
}

for my $i (1 .. 30 ) {
        for my $j (1 .. 30 ) {
                     print "[$matriz[$k][$j]] ";
}
print "\n";
}

<>;
```

That is the code of the executable.

An this one is the modules's one

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Math::Complex;

my $seed = time();
my $a = $seed / 5;
my $c = $seed - 7;
my $x = $seed;
my $m = sqrt($seed % 574) + $seed;
my $numAleatorio;


sub generadorMultiplicativo{
$numAleatorio = ((($a*$x) + $c) % $m);
$x = $numAleatorio;
}
my $letra;
my $residuo;
sub generarLetra{
   for my $i(1..30){
   generadorMultiplicativo();
    $residuo = $x/$m;

if($residuo < 0.0384615384615385 ){
       $letra = 'A';
} 
if($residuo > 0.0384615384615385 && $residuo < 0.076923076923077){
       $letra = 'B';
} 
if($residuo > 0.076923076923077 && $residuo < 0.1153846153846154){
       $letra = 'C';
}
if($residuo > 0.1153846153846154 && $residuo < 0.1538461538461538){
       $letra = 'D';
}
if($residuo > 0.1538461538461538 && $residuo < 0.1923076923076923){
       $letra = 'E';
}
if($residuo > 0.1923076923076923 && $residuo < 0.2307692307692308){
       $letra = 'F';
}
if($residuo > 0.2307692307692308 && $residuo < 0.2692307692307692){
       $letra = 'G';
}
if($residuo > 0.2692307692307692 && $residuo < 0.3076923076923077 ){
       $letra = 'H';
}
if($residuo > 0.3076923076923077 && $residuo < 0.3461538461538462){
       $letra = 'I';
}
if($residuo > 0.3461538461538462 && $residuo < 0.3846153846153846){
       $letra = 'J';
}
if($residuo > 0.3846153846153846 && $residuo < 0.4230769230769231){
       $letra = 'K';
}
if($residuo > 0.4230769230769231 && $residuo < 0.4615384615384615){
       $letra = 'L';
}
if($residuo > 0.4615384615384615 && $residuo < 0.5){
       $letra = 'M';
}
if($residuo > 0.4615384615384615 && $residuo < 0.5384615384615385){
       $letra = 'N';
}
if($residuo > 0.5384615384615385 && $residuo < 0.5769230769230769){
       $letra = 'O';
}
if($residuo > 0.5769230769230769 && $residuo < 0.6153846153846154){
       $letra = 'P';
}
if($residuo > 0.6153846153846154 && $residuo < 0.6538461538461538){
       $letra = 'Q';
}
if($residuo > 0.6538461538461538 && $residuo < 0.6923076923076923){
       $letra = 'R';
}
if($residuo > 0.6923076923076923 && $residuo < 0.7307692307692308){
       $letra = 'S';
}
if($residuo > 0.7307692307692308 && $residuo < 0.7692307692307692){
       $letra = 'T';
}
if($residuo > 0.7692307692307692 && $residuo < 0.8076923076923077){
       $letra = 'U';
}
if($residuo > 0.8076923076923077 && $residuo < 0.8461538461538462){
       $letra = 'V';
}
if($residuo > 0.8461538461538462 && $residuo < 0.8846153846153846){
       $letra = 'W';
}
if($residuo > 0.8846153846153846 && $residuo < 0.9230769230769231){
       $letra = 'X';
}
if($residuo > 0.9230769230769231 && $residuo < 0.9615384615384615){
       $letra = 'Y';
}
if($residuo > 0.9615384615384615 && $residuo < 1){
       $letra = 'Z';
}
return;
 }
}
```

I've already compiled both with perl-c , perl -V and all said it was correct.

I'm using ActivePerl 5.20 on Windows 10

Comment: Why does your title say "Issues compiling?" Are you getting compilation errors? If so, please include them in the question. If not, please fix the title to reflect the actual problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Four things to consider here:

1. The module's filename *must* be `genLetras.pm`.
2. The main script must find it. Do as @ikegami suggested in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40027345/5830574) and add

   ```
   use FindBin qw( $RealBin );
   use lib $RealBin;
   ```

   before the `use genLetras;` line.
3. The module *must* end with some *true* value else the loader will complain.
   Add the line

   ```
   1;
   ```

   as the very last line to your module.
4. The module needs a line `package genLetras;` as the first line. Add that.

#### Further notes:

- Module names – by convention – usually start with an uppercase letter, like `GenLetras`, because
  lowercase letters are reserved for pragmas (like e.g. `warnings` or `strict`).
- I use [`FindBin`](http://perldoc.perl.org/FindBin.html) usually like this:

  ```
  use FindBin;
  use lib $FindBin::Bin;
  ```

  but that's more a matter of taste.
- The `<>;` at the end of your main script *normally* is useless. I think you used it to prevent your Perl window from
  closing immediately but wait for you to press <kbd>ENTER</kbd> instead.
  That's ok then.
- I wonder why `perl -c script.pl` didn't show any errors. At my PC it did.

Answer (score 2):

During your testing, you probably set the Current Directory to be the directory in which the script resides. The module could be found because the module search paths (`@INC`) includes `.`.

When it fails, the Current Directory was probably set to some other directory. The module couldn't be found because `@INC` didn't contain the directory in which it resides.

Add the following to add the script's directory to `@INC`:

```
use FindBin qw( $RealBin );
use lib $RealBin;
```

Comment: Now it runs but it dowsnt works, it prints lots of Use of unintializad value in concatenation (.) or string at line 16 on the code from the executable

Comment: @Jairo Well, the output of `perl -wc` is quite clear: 
`Global symbol "@matriz" requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare "my @matriz"?) at so.pl line 11.
Global symbol "@matriz" requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare "my @matriz"?) at so.pl line 17.
Global symbol "$k" requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare "my $k"?) at so.pl line 17.
so.pl had compilation errors.`.